# Upgrading mysql 5.0 to mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql

I need to upgrade mysql 5.0 to mysql 5.1.
Do i need to carry out anymore steps then these.

I will log into the server and do
rpm -Uvh MySQL-server-community-5.1.63-1.rhel5.x86_64

the earlier version of mysql was installed using yum install .

Is this the correct approach ?
After installing do i need to upgrade the indvidual database themselves if so how ?

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual before such operations, back up your databases. You can use:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-database --all-databases
```

Your approach should be sufficient, but if not, you'll be able to restore everything in a clean way.

**Edit:** and you can refer to [the MySQL documentation on the subject](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html).

Comment: Can you please let me know sir what does the command mysqldump --add-drop-database --all-databases do ? And why is that your asking me to execute the command yes i have taken a backup of the database

Comment: You can of course refer to its manpage. It outputs a long file that contains a dump of all databases in SQL. It will not drop databases, just include `DROP` commands in the dump, in case you restore. A common way to use it would be with something like `mysqldump --add-drop-database --all-databases | gzip -1 > /var/lib/mysqldump.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

A backup is prudent, but it's not necessary to restore a full dump to upgrade between 5.0 and 5.1.  Just run `mysql_upgrade` from the shell after you upgrade the binaries and restart MySQL.

Note you should read the MySQL manual on upgrading: [Upgrading MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrading.html)